# Why won't this test pass?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, syntax-error

Have been trouble debugging this Ruby unit test, but can't figure what I'm doing wrong. Here is the code:

## My problem is with the best_sentence_choice method; here is what Textmate is returning to me:

```
    require 'test/unit.rb'
require 'wordplay.rb'

class TestWordPlay < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_sentences
    assert_equal(["a", "b", "c d", "e f g"], "a.b. c d. e f g".sentences)

    test_text = %q{Hello. This is a test
      of sentence separation. This is the end of the test.}
      assert_equal("This is the end of the test", test_text.sentences[2])
end

def test_words
  assert_equal(%w{this is a test}, "this is a test".words)
  assert_equal(%w{these are mostly words}, "these are, mostly, words".words)
end

# Testing best sentence choice
def test_sentence_choice
  assert_equal('This is a great test')
              WordPlay.best_sentence(['This is a test', 'This is another test', 'This is a great test']
              %w{test great this}))
  assert_equal('This is a great test', WordPlay.best_sentence(['This is a great test'],
                                                                %w{'still the best'}))

end                                                                            
end
```

## Here is what Textmate is returning:

```
    /Users/pdenlinger/ruby/wordplaylib/wordplaytest.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected tQWORDS_BEG, expecting ')'
              %w{test great this}))
                 ^
/Users/pdenlinger/ruby/wordplaylib/wordplaytest.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting kEND
              %w{test great this}))
                                  ^
```

## Can you help? Thank you!

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this line

```
WordPlay.best_sentence(['This is a test', 'This is another test', 'This is a great test'] %w{test great this}))
```

you don't seem to have a comma after the first argument. Then there are two closing parentheses but you have only one opening parentesis.

Please consider editing your question to make the code more readable (hint: if a line starts with 4 spaces and is preceded by an empty line, it'll look like code).